# Seaborn JointGrid/plot_joint: multiple scatter plots unable to annotate Rsquare

Tags: plot, seaborn, annotate

I'm having trouble with the seaborn JointGrid and plot_joint functions.  I have multiple scatter plots that I'm preforming linear regression on and I have a legend for these, but when I try to annotate the plot with the rqsuare value for each line it doesn't seem to work.  Instead it changes the color of the 1st scatter plot.

Here is a shortened version of my code (I'm plotting x and z, and using x_sections to split the data up into 4 distributions that I want the Rsquare of):

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette())
legend_labels = ['a','b','c','d']
x_sections = np.array([[1,3],[5,6],[10,11],[18,19]])
x = np.arange(1,20,0.1) #e.g. of data
z = np.random.rand(np.size(x))*x #e.g. of data

min_x= np.searchsorted(x,x_sections[0][0])
max_x= np.searchsorted(x,x_sections[0][1])
g = sns.JointGrid(x[min_x:max_x],z[min_x:max_x],xlim=(0,20),ylim=(0,20))
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,color=next(palette),label=legend_labels[0])
rsquare = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0] ** 2
#g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}",stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left")
g.plot(sns.regplot,sns.distplot)

for i in range(1,len(x_sections)):
    min_x= np.searchsorted(x,x_sections[i][0])
    max_x= np.searchsorted(x,x_sections[i][1])
    g.x = x[min_x:max_x]
    g.y = z[min_x:max_x]
    g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,color=next(palette),label=legend_labels[i])
    g.plot(sns.regplot,sns.distplot)
    #g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}",stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left")

 plt.legend()
```

This code produces a plot of the four distributions (pretty ugly, but just for the purposes of an example).  When I uncomment the g.annotate lines of code I expect the R^2 value to be annotated on the plot, but it instead changes the color of the the scatter plot distribution.  I'm not sure what is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: The annotation uses `ax.legend` (to take advantage of `loc="best"`) behavior, of which there can only be one. Since you're already writing some extra code, I'd advise you to add your own annotations with `ax.text`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm not sure how to implement this.  I can't use `g.text` and `plt.text` doesn't produce any text on the plot.  The code I posted can be pasted into python if you wouldn't mind showing me how you would implement this.  Thanks.

Comment: @mwaskom sorry forgot to tag you in my previous comment, would you mind showing me how you would implement the ax.text in the example? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the key to solving the problem is to access the axes, which are members of the [JointGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html).

Replace the old annotation:

```
g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}",stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left")
```

with the new:

```
g.ax_joint.text(xy=(1.0, 13.0), s="R^2: {:.2f}".format(
    rsquare(x[min_x:max_x],z[min_x:max_x])
))
```

But this requires that you can specify the appropriate (x, y) coordinates for your text. Using g.ax_joint.annotation(...) would also require xy coordinates. The more elegant method may be to append the r^2 value to the axis labels, within your loop.

```
...
    r_2 = rsquare(x[min_x:max_x], z[min_x:max_x])
    g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color=next(palette),
        label=legend_labels[i] + " : R^2 = {:.2f}".format(r_2))
...
```